# IAM as a Service for Social Network

Tags: amazon-iam, auth0, okta

Morning all

I am building a public web application like (Facebook, LinkedIn) which allows people from around the world to sign up and use the service for **free**.

Assuming success, there could potentially be millions of users who sign up.

With this in mind, I would prefer not to "roll-my-own" Identity and Access Management solution.

Looking at solutions such as Auth0 and Okta, I am unclear if such services would scale for my usecase.

Given many of the cloud based IAM as a Service solutions are "per-user" based, I am concerned the pricing implication would not be feasible.

In your experience, what would be a suitable platform to support IAM as a Service that would scale to millions of users.

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: Very low chances that, people will use it unless it comes with something different and a better option. There r many services already available. BTW sort of IAM can be implemented using python's any web frameworks such as pyramid, django and even in flask..., Not pretty clear on what you wanted to when you do not want per-user authentication.. anyway that's the logic part, you can implement it at your own using django groups.

Comment: Thanks. What I want is a "as a service" IAM platform which allows my 1 million users to login. Without me having to pay huge fees (As it is a free service that does not generate direct member revenue) Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS IAM is not designed for millions of users.

Look into [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) . However, there is not a free service for 1,000,000 users. Cognito is half a penny per user. ($0.00460).

If free is absolutely required look into providers such as Google, Twitter, Facebook.

[Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/)